# Add comments + Ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I've started learning rails and I would like to add ajax to comments

Comments should be added using Ajax

Can you please help or link to an example?

Here if my config.rb:

```
  resources :posts do
    resources :comments
  end
```

in post/show.html.erb

```
<p><%= @post.title %></p>

    <h2>Comments:</h2>
    <div id='com'>
      <%= render @post.comments %>
    </div>

<h2>Add a comment:</h2>
<%= render "comments/form" %>
```

in view/comments/_comment.html.erb:

```
<p>
  <strong>Commenter:</strong>
  <%= comment.commenter %>
</p>
<p>
  <strong>Comment:</strong>
  <%= comment.body %>
</p>
<%= link_to "Del", [comment.post, comment], :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %>
<hr>
```

in comments/form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for([@post, @post.comments.build], remote: true) do |f| %>
.
.
.
```

in comments_controller:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment = @post.comments.create(params[:comment])

    respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to post_path(@post) }
        format.js 
    end
  end
```

and in view add file : _create.js.erb

```
$('#com').html("<%=j render @post.comments %>");
```

without remote true
all works ( but reload page ) 
action delete works to

in application.html.erb

```
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
```

when i click to submit form - nothing happens

but when i (after submit) reload page - i saw added comment(s)

Comment: i can't see any #com id in your code?

Comment: post/show.html.erb ->  <div id='com'>

Comment: _create.js.erb it's create.js.erb and what is the output in javascript console

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to include unobtrusive javascript

in `app/assets/javascripts/application.js`

Do you have this (if not add it )

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
```

and

Answered by @DemitriyDN himself :)

rename `_create.js.erb` to `create.js.erb`

Comment: //= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree . yes i have

Comment: if you had it then y did u tick it as accepted what did you do it to run?

Comment: _create.js.erb rename to create.js.erb,  i am new in stackoverflow and i know only this  way to mark the issue as closed

Comment: @DemitriyDN, its not a compulsion to accept answers, you can accept the answer if it benefits you or you feel satisfactory. or else you can just add your own answers and mark it as correct. for other users help i have added your answer in mine. hence forth you can add your own answer if u cant get it from SO :)

Answer (score 0):

Edit your new code
in comments_controller:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment = @post.comments.create(params[:comment])

    respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to post_path(@post) }
        format.js 
    end
  end
end
```